# What principle guides word combinations with "almost"?

Tags: grammar, nouns, word-usage, adverbs

I am trying to explain to non-native speakers how to use "almost."  I can't formulate (a) rule(s) to follow with regard to nouns/pronouns.  So far, my only ideas are that almost can be collocated only with words (or in situations) that describe measurement or comparison.  However, even this seems to fail.

For example:

almost they = incorrect (no concept of measurement or comparison)

almost everyone = correct (measurement of individuals)

A platypus is almost a duck. = correct (comparison)
They are almost the same. = correct (comparison)
It is almost midnight. = correct (measurement of time vs. temporal adverbial)
We are almost there. = correct (but spatial adverbial)

However:

He wrote almost a book. = incorrect, although in this case "book" would be a comparison or perhaps a measurement of the written material

---

I am pretty much at a loss.  Thanks.

Comment: Consider also the issue of how to treat these cases: *He wrote almost an entire book* and *He wrote what was almost a book*. (Sorry, that was a complication of the question, not an answer.  :)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that while we don't say "he wrote almost a book", it is possible and not uncommon to say "he almost wrote a book", which has the same sense of measurement and benchmarking as your other examples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a standard ESL guideline for this but we ask our team/colleagues to mentally substitute **very nearly** for **almost** and see if the sentence makes sense to them.  If it does, **almost** can be used.

This isn't foolproof and probably won't make sense to native speakers, but it works in almost all the cases we encounter on a regular basis!

*PS: This is a typical ESL challenge where learners swap **most** and **almost**.  This is due to the influence of mother tongue on their sentence formation (native speakers usually won't have this issue and probably can't relate to why non-natives understand it this way). 
Another mother-tongue driven understanding that is common is that when learners say they have a **doubt**, they actually mean they have a **question**.*